# Check login always return to login fail page

Tags: php, authentication

This is my check login coding. I can't log into my system because it always return login fail. I've inserted the correct username, password and role but still it return to login fail page.

I think there is something wrong on my coding at 
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)== 1)
Btw, what does this line mean ?

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';

//to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//function to sanitize values from the form. Preventing the SQL injection
function clean ($str){
    $str = @trim($str);
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        $str = striplashes ($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//sanitize POST values
$myusername = clean ($_POST['username']);
$mypassword = clean ($_POST['password']);
$role = clean ($_POST['role']);

//input validations
if ($myusername == ''){
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Insert your username';
    $errflag = true;
}
if ($mypassword == ''){
    $errmsg_arr[]= 'Insert you password';
    $errflag = true;
}

//if there are input validation, redirect back to home
if ($errflag){
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
    session_write_close();
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}

$qry = "SELECT student.user_id, student.username, student.password, student.role FROM student WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '".md5($_POST['password'])."' and role = '$role'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);

if ($result){
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)== 1){       
        session_regenerate_id();
        $student = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
        $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']= $student['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']= $student['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_PASS']= $student['password'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_ROLE']= $student['role'];
        session_write_close();
        header("location: profile.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        header ("location: login_failed.php");
        exit();
    }
}else {
    die ("Query failed");
}

?>
```

Comment: The line in question is testing that the mysql result contains exactly one row (i.e. one student was returned).

Comment: @skrilled it should be pointed out in a comment (and someone will do that soon enough) but it shouldn't become part of the question.

Comment: @user3051803 As for your `if (mysql_num_rows($result)== 1)` line, this is asking "if one and only one record was returned", it's fine unless somehow you had two identical records.

Comment: Was the "==" issue unrelated to your problem? Or did you just fix your problem in the question itself?

Comment: Also why use `$errflag` when you can just use `if (count($errmsg_arr))` to find out if there are errors?

Comment: == is not the issue. I've fixed it and the problem is still the same. That's why i stated that it might the SELECT or something is the problem I have no idea. Btw, I did not select all rows in the table, meaning to say I just select a few like username, pass and role things that needed to log in.

Comment: You might try debugging by displaying mysql errors: `$result = mysql_query($qry) or die(mysql_error());` and by checking your row count: `echo mysql_num_rows($result)`.

Answer (score 3):

you have just one "=" in your if clause..

```
if ($myusername = ''){
    $errmsg_arr[] = 'Insert your username';
    $errflag = true;
}
```

change to:

```
  if ($myusername == ''){
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Insert your username';
        $errflag = true;
    }
```

or

```
if (empty($myusername)){
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Insert your username';
        $errflag = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
`$qry = "SELECT student.user_id, student.username, student.password, student.role FROM  student WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '".md5($_POST['password'])."' and role = '$role'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$count=0;

if ($result)
{  
while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $count++;
 $name=$result["username"];
}

 if ($count == 1) {    
    session_regenerate_id();
    $student = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
    $_SESSION['SESS_USER_ID']= $student['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME']= $student['username'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_PASS']= $student['password'];
    $_SESSION['SESS_ROLE']= $student['role'];
    session_write_close();
    header("location: profile.php");
    exit();
    }else {
    header ("location: login_failed.php");
    exit();
    }
}else {
die ("Query failed");
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two "==" in your if clauses, otherwise you're setting that variable to ''.